# Create an indicator variable in Python using a threshold value leaving NaN's as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have some float data from a conductivity probe that contains some NaN's. I would like to convert the probe data to an indicator variable based on an empirical threshold value, but I want the NaN values to stay NaNs. The conversion to indicator seems straightforward, but the problem is with handling nan's. Here is an example with a threshold value of 50:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = [0, np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x})
df['indicator'] = (df.x <=50)*1
```

Yields:

```
      x  indicator
0   0.0          1
1   NaN          0
2   2.0          1
3   3.0          1
4   4.0          1
5  51.0          0
6  61.0          0
7  71.0          0
8  81.0          0
9  91.0          0
```

But I want the indicator for nan's to be nan like so:

```
      x  indicator
0   0.0          1
1   NaN        NaN  
2   2.0          1
3   3.0          1
4   4.0          1
5  51.0          0
6  61.0          0
7  71.0          0
8  81.0          0
9  91.0          0
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code that is giving you trouble?  Data frame filtering is covered in many tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = [0, np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x})
df['indicator'] = df.x*(df.x <=50)
```

Output:

```
      x  indicator
0   0.0        0.0
1   NaN        NaN
2   2.0        2.0
3   3.0        3.0
4   4.0        4.0
5  51.0        0.0
6  61.0        0.0
7  71.0        0.0
8  81.0        0.0
9  91.0        0.0
```

For exact output:

```
mport numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = [0, np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x})
df['indicator'] = np.where(df.x.isnull(), np.nan, df.x < 50)
```

Output:

```
      x  indicator
0   0.0        1.0
1   NaN        NaN
2   2.0        1.0
3   3.0        1.0
4   4.0        1.0
5  51.0        0.0
6  61.0        0.0
7  71.0        0.0
8  81.0        0.0
9  91.0        0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1829]: df['indicator'] = df[df.x <=50]*1
```

The indicator will be set only for the rows where x <= 50:

```
In [1830]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1830]: 
      x  indicator
0   0.0        0.0
1   NaN        NaN
2   2.0        2.0
3   3.0        3.0
4   4.0        4.0
5  51.0        NaN
6  61.0        NaN
7  71.0        NaN
8  81.0        NaN
9  91.0        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought I try applying a lambda to a column :)

```
x = [0, np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91]
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x})
indicator = lambda x: np.nan if (np.isnan(x)) else (x<=50)*1 
df['indicator'] = df['x'].apply(indicator)
print(df)
```

prints:

```
      x  indicator
0   0.0        1.0
1   NaN        NaN
2   2.0        1.0
3   3.0        1.0
4   4.0        1.0
5  51.0        0.0
6  61.0        0.0
7  71.0        0.0
8  81.0        0.0
9  91.0        0.0
```